# convert bytes array to string array vyper

Tags: vyper, convert

Let's say I have a bytes array as such:

```py
Bytes[4] = b"\x00"
```

How would I convert this to a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vyper has a [convert method](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/built-in-functions.html?highlight=convert#convert) which works as a sort of type cast.

```py
myBytes: Bytes[4] = b"\x00"
myString: String[4] = convert(myBytes, String[4])
```